# Comparison of two quadratic forms

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, quadratic-forms, positive-semidefinite

Let $n \times n$ matrix $A$ be positive semidefinite and let $P$ be an orthogonal projector of some subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$ into $\mathbb{R}^n$.  Is the following correct?

$$\left( \forall x \in \mathbb{R}^n \right) \left( x^T P A P x \leq x^T A x \right)$$

Comment: I believe everything should worked on fine by using the spectral theorem.

Comment: yeah its equivalent to say that $\forall x_1,x_2\in\mathbb{R}^d$ such that $\langle x_1,x_2\rangle=0$ we have $x_1^TDx_1\leq (x_1+x_2)^TD(x_1+x_2)$ where D diagonal matrix with nonnegative entries

Comment: No its not correct!

Comment: Where does this problem come from? What is the background?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. E.g. consider $a\ge1$ and
$$
A=\pmatrix{a&1\\ 1&1},\ P=\pmatrix{1&0\\ 0&0},\ x=\pmatrix{1\\ -1}.
$$
We have $x^TPAPx=a>a-1=x^TAx$. In fact,
$$
A-PAP=\pmatrix{0&1\\ 1&1}
$$
is not positive semidefinite.